# Как убрать окно Save and Launch

Tags: eclipse

Надоело, что при каждом изменении и запуске  кода на исполнение вылезает окно Save and Launch. Как избавиться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669784/eclipse-save-files-without-asking-when-i-click-run.
на всякий случай копипаста оттуда:

> Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching.
>
> There's a setting called "Save
>   required dirty editors before
>   launching". Set it to "Always".